# Deterministic global solution to find the Optimal-knot placements for continuous piecewise linear functions to fit nonlinear data

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I have been searching lately for a deterministic global technique to linearize a nonlinear function with continuous piecewise linear regions.

I've a univariate nonlinear function y=f(x). where f(x) is monotonically increasing and non-convex function.

Problem input:
1- Data for f(x).
2- The first and last knot points are fixed and known.
3- The number of knots is pre-defined.
4- f(x) is a non-convex and monotonically increasing.

Is there a deterministic global technique to find the optimal knot placements on the nonlinear function to minimize the sum of squared errors (SSE) between the model and the data.

Question: How do I solve the problem to global min? is there any deterministic global techniques? Can anyone provide me with some literature to read, as my background is not mathematics ?

Thanks